# How to submit a letter to a device via serial communication to a Raspberry Pi and receive information back?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-communication

I am trying to send a letter from a keyboard to a device via serial communication via a Raspberry Pi Model 3 B. I need to be able to (from the code) send a letter such as a "U", "P", etc to the device in Python and be able to read the information the device sends back. I have tried to use the `serial.read()/serial.write()` commands but to no avail. I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this that I don't know. I know the device doesn't require any special type of instructions just basic serial communication.

*Extra information*:
I am using a:
-Raspberry Pi Model 3 B  **AND**  Parallax Laser RangeFinder (#28044)

Comment: Just glancing at the situation and the rangefinder, it looks like you could use pygame for the input from the keyboard and pyserial (what I'm assuming you're using already) for the output to the rangefinder

Comment: So I can simulate a keyboard press using pygame?

Comment: You can also do that, but I thought you wanted to press a physical keyboard and then have whatever you pressed sent over to the rangefinder. Either way, you can look into pygame

Comment: I've used pygame before, just not to simulate button presses. It'll be something that is always running to I wont be able to manually input the letters so knowing I can use pygame is good.

Comment: Is there anywhere that shows how to use pygame on serial communication?

Comment: No, pygame doesn't do serial communication (as far as I know). I was just recommending it in the case that you were planning on manually taking in actual physical keyboard presses the whole time. In your case, if you're automating letter messages to the rangefinder, the main thing you should be dealing with is pyserial (import serial). If that isn't working, then I'd look up general questions about using that library.

Comment: Yes I am needing to use pyserial which is where my issues are coming from. I am unable to get it to read the instructions I am sending it form the Pi.